# Selected style overriden by MouseOver style

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to style a ListBoxItem that the item is green when it is selected and lightgreen when the mouse is over the item.

This works, but when an item is selected and I move my mouse over that item, the selected style disappears. How can I fix this ?

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
                TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Margin="0,3,0,3"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Textblock"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>

                                <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGreen" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>

                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Textblock" 
                                       FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="{StaticResource AlmostWhite}" FontSize="15" Padding="5,7,5,7" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter  />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this with `StoryBoard`s, you should use simple Triggers in `ControlTemplate` to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Triggers an option for you, then you could use `MultiTriggers` to say don't apply MouseOver color when the Item is Selected.

Below is the style with MultiTriggers, and it MouserOver won't override the background when Item is selected.

```
<Style x:Key="listBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Not sure, how you can achieve this with VSM, I will be watching this thread for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Novitchi S mentioned, it would be much simpler defining this `Style` using basic `Trigger`s:

```
<Style x:Key="listBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Even if you really wanted to use a `Storyboard`, you could just add it into the `Trigger.EnterActions` section.

---

UPDATE >>>

There really is no need to use a `MultiTrigger` to achieve your requirement either. I probably didn't spot your requirement to keep the selected colour when the mouse is over the item... you just need to reverse the order of the `Trigger`s... the latter one will 'override' the behaviour of the former one:

```
<Style x:Key="listBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: You're right, storyboard & VisualStateManager was not necessary.